# When to call the super keyword of an inherited method

Tags: java, android, super

When should I call, for example, `super.onResume`? sometimes it is in the last line of the the body of `onResume` and sometimes in the first line. Is there any difference?

Comment: When you need it? It depends on what the super() method does, really. There is no way to tell when to call it in general.

Comment: it depends on you, if you want your code to run before code of super class then put super.* at the end. If you want your code to run after supper class code the put super.* at the begining. Acctualy you can put super.* wherever you want, even more than once.

Comment: when you want to call to your parent method or constructor than you can use super keyword. and also it depend on how you need. its based on your need that when you want to call your parent.

Comment: @The3211: With a super constructor, though, you don't have that choice. You have to call one, and it must be the first thing you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the use case.

For example : if the main logic is in the super class and it depends on some parameters which are expected to be provided by the child class. In that case you will first set those parameters and then call the super.
In other case, your parent class might be setting up some infrastructure like setting up some db connection or creating a proxy for remote call. And you are using that in your child class implementation. In that case first you will call super method as probably first line of your code.

A very good use case is of calling the super constructor as first line of constructor in child class to enable super class to setup all infrastructure which child class might be referring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are referring to Android's `Activity` life cycle method `onResume` (based on the Android tag). In that case, you should call it first thing, in the first line of the method.

This makes sure that the Activity is properly initialized/resumed/stopped (depending on whatever life cycle method you are overriding).

This example is from the [Android guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
    if (mCamera == null) {
        initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera init
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors. In some cases you will need to save some values before calling the super method. For the onResume() it is probably best for you to call it in the first line, but it depends. In other cases you might not even call the super method based on some calculations or boolean values. As an example, the most common case probably is the super.onBackPressed(); that I do not call if I don't want the user to be able to navigate backwards in the app flow. It can also be called outside the onBackPressed() method to emulate a back button press. So yeah, it really depends on the situation. Hope this was helpful